# How to let particular logins to work on the secondary replica only?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

We are configuring an availability group with a readable secondary replica.
A login can connect to the secondary replica using "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" in its connection string. But we came across a problem that could make our headache in future.

If the secondary replica is unavailable due to any causes when the login establishes connection, this login will be directed to the primary replica whatever it's using "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" or not.

So, my question - is there any way to ban particular logins from connecting to the primary replica if they configured for working with the secondary one?

I mean if the primary replica isn't able to direct the connection to the secondary one the connection should be closed instead of going on working on the primary replica.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU1) (KB4135048) - 13.0.5149.0 (X64) 
>     May 19 2018 09:41:57    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>     Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server
>   2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure this by setting the "Connections in primary role" setting when [configuring read-only routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-only-access-on-an-availability-replica-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). You have 2 options:

- Allow all connections (default)
- Allow read/write connections - which really means, "Connections where the Application Intent connection property is set to ReadOnly are not allowed. This can help prevent customers from connecting a read-intent work load to the primary replica by mistake."

This setting isn't configured at the login level though - this relies on what you said in the first part of your question, that your logins are using ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly in their connection string.

If they don't ask for that specifically - meaning, if they don't declare that they're only going to write - then SQL Server has no fast way of knowing that they have no writeable permissions in any database, on any object. After all, they could even execute a stored procedure signed with a cert, and that cert could allow them to do writes.

So if you really want to stop them from logging in even if they don't use ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly, then I'd do it by simply disabling their logins on the primary. Then, run an Agent job every minute on every replica, checking to see if this particular replica is a primary. If a failover has occurred, and this replica is now a primary, disable the reporting-only logins. If the replica is a secondary, and the reporting-only logins are disabled, then enable them.

This will of course run into problems if you really do want to disable someone's login - it'll instantly be enabled again in a minute.

Comment: Nice stuff Brent. How about rather than a job running every minute on every node that you create an alert on each node that triggers a local job when error 19406 is thrown (replica state change)?

Comment: Kevin - sure, you could do that. (I wouldn't - I would just worry about the error failing for some reason, and missing the status change - but I'd be okay with people doing it.)